# Changing one element of an array of arrays with event

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have two drop down menus, which allows the user to select the x & y axis of a scatterplot. In the scatterplot there's also a linear regression line plotted, so I'd like to have it updated as the values on the two axis are changed.
To do so I have to change the two arrays of the `var points` accordingly, to change the values of the x and/or y axis

```
var points = dataset.map(function (d) { return [parseFloat(d.x), parseFloat(d.y)]; });
```

(I use this kind of array because I'm using a js library to calculate the values of the regression)
The `d.x` contains the values of the x axis, `d.y` the y axis'.
What I'd like to do is to be able to change just the first or second array within the array itself (`d.x` or `d.y`).

To do so I put the variable inside the event listener but here's the problem I don't know how to solve:
Since there will be `two event listeners`, one for d.x and one for d.y, how can I say in the event listener to just change the `d.x` or `d.y` value of the array?
For now I have for the x axis:

```
.on("change", function () { //other stuff happening, then:
var points = dataset.map(function (d) { return [parseFloat(d[SelX]), parseFloat(d.y)]; });
```

The `SelX` refers to the x axis value changed, and works, but I'd like it not to change also the `d.y` value in the array, I don't know the proper syntax to write that without affecting also the second value of the array.
Or maybe could be better this solution:
Since the `var points` is stated before the `.on change` event, is it possible to refer to the first or second array so I don't have to paste the whole thing inside the event listener?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What are these event listeners you're talking about? It also looks like `d.x` and `d.y` are individual values and not arrays.

Comment: I'll edit the first post to make things more clear

Comment: I hope this way is more understandable! I'm having a hard time explaining what I want to do with words today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the easiest thing to do would be to keep references to the currently selected values for both x and y in global variables. Then the code would look something like this.

```
var chosenX = "foo", chosenY = "bar";

// ...
.on("change", function() {
  chosenX = SelX;
  points = dataset.map(function (d) { return [parseFloat(d[chosenX]), parseFloat(d[chosenY])]; });
});
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that to make this work I did the following:
var chosenX = d3.keys(dataset[0]).filter(function (d) { return d == "foo"; }); 
var chosenY = d3.keys(dataset[0]).filter(function (d) { return d == "bar"; });